# Is there any reason to exercise company stock options with no listed value?

Tags: employee-stock-options

I have vested options that are relatively cheap to buy, but there is no indication that there is a traded underlying security and there is no value listed anywhere on Carta.  Since the exercise price doesn't change (right?) and there is no value or even ticker / link to value listed, is there any reason to exercise these options?

Comment: The value of the company is at least the book value. Some states allow stockholders to request a copy of the company books ! Also, look at revenue and income to arrive at a gross-margin or a net-margin, look at revenue growth, and decide on a P/E ratio to apply.

Comment: @SSpring if the shares aren't traded publicly in a market isn't the value zero practically?  A potential but currently unrealizable "value"?

Comment: The value is to interested partners and often in a profitable company. But in this situation many investors do want a partnership tax structure and then receive income minus agreed re-investment. Or my editorial corporation has a portfolio in addition to core operations and then the company features a liquid net asset value. There is no C-corp dividend but just growth in value of the corporation.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Michael's reasons, a couple more:

- If you exercise when the strike/exercise price is the same as the fair market value (FMV), you won't have to pay alternative minimum tax (AMT).
- If you exercise when the value of the company is under $50 million, and then wait 5 years to sell, you may be able to exclude the entire capital gain via the [qualified small business stock (QSBS) deduction](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/q/qsbs-qualified-small-business-stock.asp).

Comment: "If you exercise when the strike/exercise price is the same as the [FMV]..." - there is no FMV listed anywhere that I know of.

Comment: @HorseHair, it may not be listed publicly, but the share do have a value. You may need to ask whoever is in charge of equity at your company to find out what it is. Usually the strike price is based on the FMV at the time the options are issued, but if your company has grown (or shrunk) at all since then, it will be different.

Comment: Why would you exercise when FMV equals the strike? That throws away the value of the option. Buying stock at FMV is not a benefit; it is just a neutral exchange (no effect on your net worth), and you're now exposed to the risk of the stock going down, which was not the case while holding the options. Saying it avoids AMT seems like letting the tax tail wag the financial dog, cutting off one's nose to spite one's face, etc. You can always avoid taxes by not making any money.

Comment: @nanoman It's a gamble but if it's a startup (as it sounds like this is), the strike price is probably low so it's not a lot of money to risk, and the tax savings could be really significant, especially if it qualifies for QSBS.

Answer (score 2):

Only if they will expire soon, most likely if you leave the company. In which case you'll have to decide if you want to gamble by purchasing shares in a private company they may never become liquid.

Also there can be tax reasons: Your Long Term Capital Gains clock starts when you receive the shares. There's a bit of detail around the technicalities here, so talk to a pro if you're not sure.